# How to use output from match function to write if function based on value from indexed row

Tags: r, matching

I have a hierarchical data frame (df) that looks like this, where if the Document value is "NA" then the corresponding SubDoc represents the highest level of document

```
 Document       SubDoc           Level
 *NA*           Document1        "1"
 Document1      SubDocument1     "NA"
 Document1      SubDocument2     "NA" 
 Document1      SubDocument3     "NA" 
 Document1      SubDocument4     "NA"
 SubDocument1   Outcome1         "NA"
 SubDocument1   Outcome2         "NA"
 SubDocument1   Outcome3         "NA"
 Subdocument2   Outcome1         "NA"
 Subdocument2   Outcome2         "NA"
 Subdocument3   Outcome1         "NA"
 *NA*           Document2        "1"
 Document2      SubDoc1          "NA"
```

Etc...

I want Levels to represent the number of levels down the document is from the top and currently I assign level 1 by checking if the Document column is empty and if so assigning it 1

```
df$Level <- ifelse(is.na(df$Document), df$Level <- "1", df$Level <- "NA")
```

Now I want to assign all the levels below that by checking if strings in the document column have match in the SubDoc column (because the row they match with would contain what level its parent is)

```
match(df$Document,df$Subdoc)
```

which returns an index of where they matched in this case

```
"NA",1,1,1,1,2,2,2
```

What I want to do is take those index numbers and write a statement where if the Level value of the row index that was returned == 1 then the Level would get 2, so for example row 2 found a match in row 1 and in that row, the Level == 1 therefore the Level value for row 2 would be 2. The resulting data frame would look like this

```
 Document       SubDoc           Level
 *NA*           Document1        "1"
 Document1      SubDocument1     "2"
 Document1      SubDocument2     "2" 
 Document1      SubDocument3     "2" 
 Document1      SubDocument4     "2"
 SubDocument1   Outcome1         "3"
 SubDocument1   Outcome2         "3"
 SubDocument1   Outcome3         "3"
 Subdocument2   Outcome1         "3"
 Subdocument2   Outcome2         "3"
 Subdocument3   Outcome1         "3"
 *NA*           Document2        "1"
 Document2      SubDoc1          "2"
```

However I'm unsure on how to write out a solution for this. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem using the following code

```
df$level[is.na(df$Document)] <- 1

df["ParentLevel"] <- df[match(df$Document,df$Subdoc),"level"]

df$level[df$ParentLevel == 1] <- 2

df["ParentLevel"] <- df[match(df$Document,df$Subdoc),"level"]

df$level[Sub_docs$ParentLevel == 2] <- 3

df["ParentLevel"] <- df[match(df$Document,df$Subdoc),"level"]

df$level[df$ParentLevel == 3] <- 4
```

etc...
From here it's just a matter of creating a loop and dropping the ParentLevel Column from the dataset. The output looks like this,

```
Document       SubDoc          Level
 *NA*           Document1        1
 Document1      SubDocument1     2
 Document1      SubDocument2     2 
 Document1      SubDocument3     2 
 Document1      SubDocument4     2
 SubDocument1   Outcome1         3
 SubDocument1   Outcome2         3
 SubDocument1   Outcome3         3
 Subdocument2   Outcome1         3
 Subdocument2   Outcome2         3
 Subdocument3   Outcome1         3
 *NA*           Document2        1
 Document2      SubDoc1          2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `match`

```
df$Level <- match(df$Document, unique(df$Document))
df$Level
#[1] 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

---

Or with `factor`

```
as.integer(factor(df$Document, levels = unique(df$Document)))
```

NOTE: Here, it is not clear whether the OP's dataset have real `NA` or with quoted strings `"NA"`

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Document = c(NA, "Document", "Document", "Document", 
"Document", "SubDocument1", "SubDocument1", "SubDocument1"), 
    SubDoc = c("Document", "SubDocument1", "SubDocument2", "SubDocument3", 
    "SubDocument4", "Outcome1", "Outcome2", "Outcome3"), Level = c(1L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: This just assigns unique values to each of the Documents, in my current dataset there are multiple sets of documents each with subdocuments and in the example I gave each of the subdocuments would also have outcomes associated with them. This is where I'm struggling. Apologies if my explanation wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @LAM can you please change your example so that it is more clear.  From your example, it seems that this is working

Comment: I've updated the example dataset to hopefully provide a better understanding of the problem I'm working with